# Word-break: break-all; - what's to replace with?

Tags: html, css, width

I have this:

```
 <div style="word-break: break-all; width 50px;">... long text ...</div>
```

It works just as I'd like to

But the editor says:

```
 CSS validation: 'word-break' is not  avalid CSS property name.
```

What should I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`word-break` is valid indeed, but only in CSS3. Are you sure that your validator is set to CSS3 rather than CSS2 or lower?

Answer (score 0):

It seems `word-break` is a CSS3 property. There is no CSS alternative and your editor is most likely not up to date with the latest CSS standards.